# How can I align an Icon to top of Text?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

This is how I want this to look like

[image]
Notice that the text is always a number.

How can I align the top of the Heart to the red line (top of text)?

If I can remove the font padding (over the red line and below the number) this also could work for me fine but I do not know how to do this.

This is my code

```kotlin
Row {
            Text(
                pulse.toString(),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Gray),
                fontSize = 60.sp,
                color = vitalModifier.color)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Green)
                    .alignBy(LastBaseline),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_heart),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = vitalModifier.color)
        }
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a picture of how you want it to look? I can't understand where you want to position the heart exactly

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added an image of how I want it to look

Comment: you'll have to make a custom modifier to access the text's `AlignmentLine`s and position your content based on that line

Answer (score 5):

You can use **BadgedBox** to achieve this

```
BadgedBox(badge = { Badge { Text("8") } }) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                        contentDescription = "Favorite"
                    )
                }
```

https://dev.to/farhanroy/jetpack-compose-badge-18ho

[image]