# Android Jetpack Compose - How to display badge on Image?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to display a badge on an Image?

I'm trying to achieve this:
[image]

How to get that green color circle on the image?

Comment: Custom Layout is the only way I can suggest you

Comment: Take the layouts codelab

Comment: What about BadgedBox, it's still experimental tho.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I align an Icon to top of Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281119/how-can-i-align-an-icon-to-top-of-text)

Answer (score 2):

As a simple example to get an idea:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp)) {
   Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = "Contact profile picture",
        modifier = Modifier
            // Set image size to 40 dp
            .size(40.dp)
            // Clip image to be shaped as a circle
            .clip(CircleShape)
    )
    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)){
        Text(text = "", modifier = Modifier.width(28.dp))
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            contentDescription = "",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Black),
            modifier = Modifier
                // Set image size to 4 dp
                .size(8.dp)
                // Clip image to be shaped as a circle
                .clip(CircleShape)

        )
    }
}
```

As a result I see
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using this -

import the androidx.compose.material //required datas

```
BadgedBox(
badge = {
    Badge(backgroundColor=Green) { Text("8") } 
}
  ){
   //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be using badge box -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090300/12228079

[image]

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.